# Create table in magento module

Tags: mysql, sql, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am new in magento. How can I create table in db ? I tried some code, but  table didn't create. But in core_resource table I have  setup my  table. The version of my  php file  is  match  with version of my  config file. Help me  please, I am  looking answer for that question  two days , but nowhere can find  anything.

Comment: is the below answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create a table.

1. You can create table by direct `phpmyadmin`
2. write own sql and run that by php file

Both ways are applicable on magento too.

but if you are trying to create your own table by your own `custom module` then you have to play with `xml` and magento `models`.

I am providing you an example of module.

**XML**

```
 <models>
        <magenotification>
            <class>Magestore_Magenotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>magenotification_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </magenotification>
        <magenotification_mysql4>
            <class>Magestore_Magenotification_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <magenotification>
                    <table>magenotification</table>
                </magenotification>
                <feedback>
                    <table>magenotification_extension_feedback</table>
                </feedback>         
                <feedbackmessage>
                    <table>magenotification_extension_feedbackmessage</table>
                </feedbackmessage>                          
                <logger>
                    <table>magenotification_log</table>
                </logger>
                <license>
                    <table>magenotification_license</table>
                </license>
            </entities>
        </magenotification_mysql4>
    </models>
```

SQL

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('magenotification_extension_feedbackmessage')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('magenotification_extension_feedback')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('magenotification_log')};
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('magenotification')};

CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('magenotification')} (
  `magenotification_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `notification_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (`notification_id`, `url`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`magenotification_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('magenotification_log')} (
  `log_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `extension_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `license_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `license_key` text NOT NULL default '',
  `check_date` date NOT NULL,
  `sum_code` varchar(255),
  `response_code` smallint(5),
  `expired_time` varchar(255),
  `is_valid` tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('magenotification_extension_feedback')} (
  `feedback_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `extension` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `extension_version` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `coupon_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `coupon_value` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `expired_counpon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL default '',
  `file` text NOT NULL default '',
  `comment` text NOT NULL default '',
  `latest_message` text NOT NULL default '',  
  `latest_response` text NOT NULL default '',
  `latest_response_time` datetime,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `is_sent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feedback_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('magenotification_extension_feedbackmessage')} (
  `feedbackmessage_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `feedback_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feedback_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_customer` tinyint(1) default '2',
  `message` text NOT NULL default '',
  `file` text NOT NULL default '',
  `posted_time` datetime NULL,
  `is_sent` tinyint(1) default '2',
  PRIMARY KEY (`feedbackmessage_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

You have to learn how to [create custom module](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) in magento for more information.

[custom module with database](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)